# how to create a fake rails' `request` object to test a gem with rspec

Tags: rspec, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am developing a gem, which one of its functions will authenticate the incoming request to the controller, and I want to test it. but I don't know how can I fake a rails' `request` object and send it to the function to test its behavior, who can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need https://github.com/bblimke/webmock or its analogs

Comment: How would you be able to use webmock to create a fake request object?